# Maven Repository URL

Tags: maven

I am new to maven and trying to understand how it works.
I am using maven to build my project. It download the jars that I have listed in pom.xml file. I do Maven Intall (eclipse), it downloads the jar file in my .m2/repository folder. Everything works well but I cannot figure out how it knows to pull the jar files from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. In which file, this url is defined. I do not have setting.xml file in .m2/repository and I do not have reference to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ in pom.xml. I searched everywhere in my project but no references to this URL. Just wondering which file has this URL.

thank you so much

Comment: Maven itself has this URL internally defined by default. You can execute maven on command line as well... you don't need to do a `mvn install` usually `mvn package` or maybe you might need `mvn verify` if you have defined integration tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Maven Central Repository* is defined in the Maven "[Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#super-pom)".